# Convert key-value array to object using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array with key value sequence (first element is a key, second - value etc.)

```
var arr = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3];
```

I need to convert this array to object using lodash. How can I do this?

```
result = {
  a : 1,
  b : 2,
  c : 3
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's every other value, you could just reduce that

```js
var arr = ['a',1,'b',2,'c',3];

var obj = arr.reduce( (a,b,i) => {return i%2===0 ? (a[arr[i]] = arr[i+1],a) : a}, {});

console.log(obj)
```